# rewrite an equation in matrix form to summation form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

Let $i=1,...,n$ and $j=1,....,p$ and let $x_{ij} $ a matrix  $n×p $, and  $D $ is a diagonal matrix  $n×n $
We have this equation  $N=X^TDX $ , where  $N $ is a  $p×p $ matrix. I need to write  $N $ as a summation form, any help please;

my code in R and in summation form;  $N=∑_{i=1}^{n}∑_{i=1}^{p}∑_{i=1}^{k} x_{ij} x_{ik} d_{ii} $

In R

```
 N=matrix(0,nrow=p,ncol=p)
 for(j in 1:p){
 for(j in 1:k){
 N[k,j]=sum(((X[,j])^2)%*%(mu*(1-mu)))
 }}
```

But it still gives me wrong result ..

Comment: I'm not familiar with R, but using the same index ($j$) in both `for` loops seems wrong, or risky.

Comment: I would suggest you to check you summation form, I found you should change it a little, some thing like;
$N=∑_{i=1}^{n}∑_{j=1}^{p} x_{ji}  d_{ii}x_{i,j}$
Then try to optimize your code by x(i,j)=x(j.i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is the $n \times p$ matrix with entries $x_{ij}$ and $D$ is the $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with entries $d_{ij}$.  Let $B = DX$.  Then $B$ is an $n \times p$ matrix with entries $b_{ij} = \Sigma_{k=1}^n d_{ik}x_{kj} = d_{ii}x_{ij}  $ since $D$ is diagonal.

Let $A$ be $X^T$.  So $A$ is the $p \times n$ matrix with entries $a_{ij}$ where $a_{ij} = x_{ji}$.  Then the $ij^{th}$ entry of $X^TDX$ is the $ij^{th}$ entry of $AB = \Sigma_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj} = \Sigma_{k=1}^n x_{ki}d_{kk}x_{kj}$.

Comment: what about $N=∑_{i=1}^{n} x_{ij} x_{ik} d_{ii} $ where $k = 1, ..., p$

Comment: Yes.  Your sum gives you the $kj^{th}$ entry of the $p \times p$ matrix.  Notice it is the same as my sum but with the $i$'s and $k$'s swapped.  My sum gives the $ij^{th}$ entry so yours gives the entry in row $k$ and column $j$.